# Troubleshooting Symfony2 - Missing Entity Property

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine

My co-worker made a tweak to the db last night without telling me. Field books.pages became books.pages_short & books.pages_long. I figured out what had happened and went in to change/add the fields by hand in Entity/Books, Resources/config/doctrine/Books.orm.yml and Form/BooksTypes + whatever twigs referred to that specific field. But in trying to display the titles/index page I still get:

```
Property ABC\LibraryBundle\Entity\Books::$pages does not exist
500 Internal Server Error - ReflectionException
```

Note that in the Entity/Books.php I changed the books property to 2 separate ones pages_short & pages_long (including any references in the annotations) and also in the getters and setters.

I also clear:cached in both dev & prod (though I'm only in dev) but I'm still getting an error which refers to the $pages variable (with space after) which no longer exists in the code base. New variables are all $pages_[short|long]

DB changes will happen and you need to be prepared for them. I believe I'm making the change in every place where the field reference exists, so trying to figure out how to troubleshoot this error.

Comment: "DB changes will happen and you need to be prepared for them. " - this is not the way to be prepared for them - checkout Doctrine Migrations. ;)

Does the error not include any file and line number? Can you use XDebug?

Comment: Right, I mean to say, this is my first time with Doctrine and I need to make sure I know how to handle these changes :). The top item in the stack trace is doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService.php at line 79 ... and it goes down to a call to the BooksController indexAction() ... I can add the entire stack trace w/line #s (11 items) to the indexAction if that will help provide clarity. Thx

Comment: I would suggest using xdebug to traverse the stack and find where that variable comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

I bet there is a listener somewhere that is still using the ´$pages´ field of your Books entity.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you have updated your schema, try to delete the cache/ prod & cache /dev